# How would I escape a paradox if vampire goes back in time to create the first one?

Tags: plot, timelines

My story is set a few hundred thousand years *after* the first vampire was made. No new vampire knows how they started, only they were turned by a vampire. Those old vampires would get killed off (eventually), leaving a new generation, the cycle continues on.

Now, I want to try and have the vampire origins start by a vampire going to the past to create the first but that presents me with a few confusing paradoxes I want to get past for a Stable Time Loop.

The transformation is through venom so the logical choice would be to bite a human and leave them to turn, thus creating the vampire cycle to start with but could potentially lead to the Grandfather Paradox due to the venom side of the transformation or does the genetic diversity of each vampire between the first vampire and the Traveler!Vampire changes the paradox?

I have considered the 'venom' to be manufactured separately from the vampire itself but using the study of the original venom but I don't know if that establishes the time loop from a Bootstrap Paradox.

Answer (score 2):

Well first you would need a reason for the vampire to go back that is not them going back to make the first since in theory why would they need to go back and make the first vampire when they are already around.

Once you have a reason you can make it that the first vampire would have been made without intervention and that the vampire that travels back in time ends up messing up the creation of the first and therefore has to fill in for the first.

For example say that subject zero is the first vampire and he bites the second person to be turned starting the cycle. However subject zero in the original timeline died right after they turned the second person disappearing from history, as where the vampire that travelled back ends up resulting in the first getting killed before they turn the second into a vampire before going back to his own time the vampire turns the second then disappears from history getting the same result as the first vampire was still the one start the cycle without changing history.

Or you can make it that the vampire that has ended up travelling back in time for whatever reason ends up becoming subject zero they weren't meant to be subject zero but end up as it cause they went back. Events play off with the vampire starting off the cycle, but even if he didn't go back someone else would have become subject zero and ended up starting the vampire race.

Basically fix the paradox by making it that even though vampire changes the past it won't change the future cause events play out in a way that isn't too different for the original timeline.

Otherwise I can't see any way to escape the paradox.